# cant open a socket connection from visual studio 2019 to a loopback 127.0.0.1:5000

Tags: c#, .net, network-programming

```
Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(this.getRemoteAddress()), this.getPort());
socket.Connect(remoteEP);
```

while trying to run this part of the code i receive the following error:

> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException    HResult=0x80004005    Message=No
> connection could be made because the target machine actively refused
> it 127.0.0.1:5000

this happens both for loop-back and for outside connection,

i checked that the function receives the correct ip:port,
and that there is a listener open on that port.
i have checked the firewall and it is off.
it works fine from a coworkers computer when i open a connection to a listener that is running on my computer.

something that i think might have a role in this issue:
i had a problem with my WiFi connection a week ago and a network admin played with my computer and fixed the issue, before that the part of code listed above worked fine for me.

i have tried everything i could find on google.
any ideas on how to debug this issue?

Comment: have you tried to simply use localhost:5000? This should fix the error

Comment: Well then ask your network admin what he did change. He clearly broke something.